# ASP.net: Calling a webmethod from ajax javascript. [vb.net]

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I'm creating dynamically a Popup-Extender with some controls. One control is a Button which has the "onclick" attribute and has to call the JavaScript method submit. I'm creating the Popup-Extender and it's controls in "SiteMaster.vb". the attribute "onclick" of the button is set in the "click-Event" of the Button which calls the "modalpopup.show" Method. The created html-Code which i can see with the developer-tool from my Browser is:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$button_buttontestfooter_50_0_0" value="test" onclick="submit();" id="button_buttontestfooter_50_0_0" runat="server">
```

In my opinion everything looks fine until now. I have written the JavaScript Method "submit" in the Source of Site.Master:

```
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title></title>
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit() {
        alert("blaaaaa");
        console.log("jijijij");
        window.open("http://www.google.de");
        var dataValue = "{'name': 'Niklas'}";
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "http://localhost:53470/GetCurrentTime",
            data: dataValue,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType:'json',
            error: function (a, b, c) {
                console.log("jijijij")
                alert(a + ":" + b + "::::" + c);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("hallo");
                alert("" + data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
```

At Default.aspx.vb i have written the webmethod:

```
Public Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()>
Public Shared Function GetCurrentTime(ByVal name As String) As String
    Return name
End Function
```

But I have the feeling that JavaScript method is never called because I cannot see that in the logs in browser console as I have put console.log() Method in JavaScript function which is being called.

Comment: `contentType: 'application/jason'` it should be `contentType: 'application/json'` and

Comment: `contentType: 'application/json'` and `dataType:'json'` should be there

Answer (score 0):

The input type you have used is `submit`, so once you click this button it won't call javascript function, and will directly submit the form. So instead of this please change use `type="button"` to call `JavaScript` function

Comment: The problem is, i create a new Button with vb.net. in code behind. so how do i change the type = "Button"... the input type="submit" is created bey visual studio ...

Comment: Can you show me the code which is generating that button? better if you show .aspx code as well

Comment: When i click this button, the popup disapears... @hdkhardik

Comment: Even if i put an alert at the beginning at the JavaScript method submit, it doesnt show the alert ( alert("blaaaaa");)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub ButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim LayoutDef As ASPGlobalHandling.LayoutDefinition = p.Layout_Load("sessionitem_layouts", 0, "footer", "", False)
    ctrl.Container_LoadControls(updPnlContent.ContentTemplateContainer, 0, LayoutDef.Layout, "", 0)
    Dim c3po As Control = p.Container_FindControl(updPnlContent, "button_buttontestfooter_50_0_0")
    If TypeOf (c3po) Is Button Then
        Beep()
        Dim c3po1 As Button = CType(c3po, Button)
        c3po1.Text = "test"
        c3po1.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "submit();")
    End If
    modalPopUp.Show()
End Sub
```

This is the button event where i call modalpopup.show. in the method load Container_LoadControls the button is generating. later i add the attribute onklick

Comment: When i click this button, the popup disapears... @hdkhardik

Comment: add attribute like this,
c3po1.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "submit();")

Comment: the popup doesnt dissapear now :) but the alert is still not showing.

Comment: Did you check that function is being called or not ?

Comment: i wanted to check it with help of the alert... i thought, when i see the alert, i can be sure the javascriptfunction is called. the alert(); function is in the begining if the submit javascriptfunction.

Comment: keep break point at first line of javascript function, and try to debug if it is executing or not.

Comment: in Site.Master (Source), i cant put a breakpoint... i have different methods. with this methods at the beginning of the submit-Function i wanted to see id the function is called:

Comment: When i click the button, which i am creating in the button-klick event, the button dissapears. only the buttons which i createt bevor this click-event for the modalpopup                                                                           [modalPopUp = New ModalPopupExtender()
        modalPopUp.ID = "modalPopupId"
        modalPopUp.TargetControlID = dummyBtn.ID
        modalPopUp.CancelControlID = dummyBtn.ID
        modalPopUp.OkControlID = dummyBtn.ID
        modalPopUp.PopupControlID = updPnlPopup.ID] are still in the popup... i am not sure, if this has something to do ...

Comment: i put now a breakpoint in my explorer with the developertool at the beginning of the JavaScript method submit, but still nothing happens if i press the button which has the ClientOnClick-Attribute...

Answer (score 0):

I just saw that the Javascript-Method "submit" can be called from the buttons which are not created in the ButtonClick()-Event. Someone has a solution?